# How to use Predicate in EJB and fix the used engine to ejb but not appclient?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I'm deploying an EJB application inside glassfish, and want it to use the ejb engine for my application. However, when I add Predicate to my remote class it changes the engine to appclient instead of ejb.

```
    @Override
    public int getNombreAjourne(String filiere, String classe) throws 
    Exception {
          List<Student> allStudents = Parser.getStudents();

          // Deleting this line fix the problem
          Predicate<Student> byFiliereAndClasse = student -> 
          student.getFiliere().equals(filiere)
          && student.getClasse().equals(classe) 
          && student.getMoyenne() < 10;

          return allStudents.size();
    }
```

Comment: I had the same problem. It seems some classes but not only Predicate triggers this problem. For example using Collections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by downgrading my jdk from jdk11 to 1.8.
I hope this will help someone :)